# Command to open a document

Tags: command-line

What's the command that, given a document name, will open it with the right application (i.e. an equivalent to windows start / mac os x open)

Comment: By "document" I meant any non-executable file, including PNG, MP3, or whatever

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `xdg-open file` this should open the file with the correct program, that is defined via mimetypes

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean Document Viewer. The command name is `evince`. Optionally with filename as argument. More at manpage.